# Как Vector2.angle из диапазона от 180 до -180 преобразовать в диапазон от 0 до 360?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: Это джойстик]

```
float angle = Vector2.Angle(center.transform.position, shootJoystick.Direction);
hand.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
```

Нахожу угол между синей точкой (*center.transform.position*) и красной (*shootJoystick.Direction*)

 Проворачиваю руку персонажа на этот угол (*hand.transform.rotation*) 
 Проблема в том, что она вращается полукругом. Как Vector2.angle из диапазона от 180 до -180 преобразовать в диапазон от 0 до 360?

Comment: Если меньше нуля, то добавить 360?

Comment: @MBo Я на девять секунд раньше :).

Comment: @Igor Да уж, не думай  о мгновеньях свысока :)

Comment: Проверил, не работает. Странно, должно по логике работать, ну кроме -180.

Comment: Решил проверить через Log дак он не от -180 до 180, а от 0 до 180... Круг причём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C учётом последних данных - посчитайте угол через atan2

```
 angle = atan2(shootJoystick.Direction.y - center.transform.position.y,
               shootJoystick.Direction.x - center.transform.position.x)
```

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне повернуть на радианы?)

Comment: если у вас atan2 даёт градусы, а повороту требуются радианы, умножьте на Pi/180

Comment: atan2 выдаёт -3.071808 и тп +- от -3.072 до -3.071

Comment: ок, значит радианы от -пи до пи

Comment: Немного не понял... На удивление просто от -пи до -пи с точностью до миллионных...

Comment: Спасибо, помог. Почитал немного о atan2 и вот что вышло
`float angle = Mathf.Atan2(shootJoystick.Direction.y / center.transform.position.y, shootJoystick.Direction.x / center.transform.position.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 180;`

Answer (score 2):

Прибавить к отрицательному углу 360 градусов.

Comment: можно взять остаток от деление `angle % 360`

Answer (score 2):

прибавить к углу 180 градусов

`Vectoe2.angle() + 180`

Comment: Теперь диапазон от 180 до 360. Полукруг ушёл в минус